# How can I update to macOS 10.12.1 (16B2657)?

Tags: mac, software-update, macos, build-version

I'm trying to develop apps that use the new MacBook Pro's Touch Bar.

On [Apple Developer's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/macos/touch-bar/), it states that at least Build 16B2657 is required.

> To develop apps that use the Touch Bar, your Mac will need to run Xcode 8.1 on macOS Sierra 10.12.1 (16B2657) or later.

---

However, I have Build 16B2555 installed. As seen on Wikipedia, it seems like both Builds 16B2555 and 16B2657 are of version 10.12.1. However, one's released before the other.

> [image: Image 1]

I've tried to check for updates in the App Store but there doesn't show any.

---

I also tried downloading it from [Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/kb/dl1897?locale=en_US). But it doesn't seem to install:

> [image: Image 2]

---

### So, how can I update to Build 16B2657?

Comment: I'd suggest downloading the Sierra installer from the Mac App Store and installing it that way. If all else fails you can wait for 10.12.2 ;)

Comment: And 10.12.2 is here now. Could you install this update?